# Lock the cursor to trackball view

Tags: c#

I have a simple implementation of a trackball which rotates a a sphere with mouse movement using HelixViewport3D in C#.

I need to lock the movement of the cursor to closely match the rotation of the sphere so that a movement on x and the y of the cursor will closely match the rotation of the trackball.  Currently the trackball rotates at a much greater rate.  I have been adjusting the rotation sensitivity but I wondered if there is a better solution.

```
  <Window x:Class="HelixTest.MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:h="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
        Title="Getting Started Demo" Height="500" Width="500">

    <h:HelixViewport3D x:Name="ViewPort" 
                       CameraRotationMode="Trackball" 
                       IsZoomEnabled="False" 
                       IsTouchZoomEnabled="False" 
                       IsPanEnabled="False"
                       IsInertiaEnabled="True" 
                       RotationSensitivity="0.11"
                       ShowViewCube="False" 
                       ShowFrameRate="False" 
                       ShowCameraInfo="True"
                       ShowCameraTarget="False">
        <h:DefaultLights/>
        <h:SphereVisual3D x:Name="Ball"  Radius="9.4" Fill="#FF802121"/>
    </h:HelixViewport3D>
    </Window>
```